# Extra 0.1cm after setting geometry top margin

Tags: header-footer, margins, geometry, viewers

I try to set 3cm for top margin of the paper with `geometry` package. After I measure the real length of top margin with PDF, this is actually 3.1 cm. There are a 0.1 extra space there.
Also, I spot many inconsistencies with  below margin. At one page it is exactly 3cm. At many pages it exceeds or lack 0.1cm from exact wanted margin.

Beside `geometry`, I also use `fancydhr`, and customize some native pagestyle. Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,headheight=0pt,left=4cm,top=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.5cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
{% 
\fancyhf{}% 
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% 
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\bo{Dummy University}}}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}%
\begin{document}
Some text blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

Where actually bottom margin of `geometry` is measured from bottom side of paper? Right below 'g' or 'e'? Or--though I think it is least unlikely--it is just a flaw from pdf viewer used to measure size?

Comment: Did you measure it on-screen at 100% zoom? Or did you print it out? If printed, remove any "fit to page margins" options of the printer.

Comment: On-screen. PDF-Xchange viewer has its unique tool so user could measure any distance in one pdf document

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `report` class uses `\raggedbottom`, so it's normal that the bottom line is not at 3cm exactly from the bottom side of the paper. The distance is measured from the baseline, so where the “e” sits.

If you measure the top distance, you should get that the first baseline sits 3cm + 12pt (the value of the `\topskip` parameter). An uppercase letter is (with the Computer Modern fonts) 8.2pt high. So, if you measure from the top side to the top of an uppercase letter in the first line, you should have a distance of

> 3cm + (12-8.2)pt = 3.13cm

which accords with your measurement.

On the other hand, an integer number of lines doesn't fill 23.7cm (29.7-3-3). Let's see why: the first line occupies 12pt and successive baselines are 14.5pt apart from each other. The text block area is 23.7cm = 674.33pt high; so you can fit 46 lines, which occupy

> (45*14.5 + 12)pt = 664.5pt

and so 9.83pt are missing, that is 0.35cm (in a page where only continuous text is typeset, no title or other object).

If you add the `showframe` option to the call of `geometry`, you get this for the top:

[image: top]

where you see the line where the 3cm are measured from, slightly above the “A”.

Here's a picture of the bottom:

[image: bottom]

where the missing 3.5mm are clearly visible.

Here is the result after adding

```
\setlength{\topskip}{8.2pt}
\linespread{1.02}
```

so the baselineskip will be 14.5*1.02=14.79 and

> 14.79*45 + 8.2 = 673.75

(which is just 0.58pt from 674.33pt = 23.7cm). Top:

[image: new top]

and bottom:

[image: new bottom]

I wouldn't bother, though.

Comment: _An uppercase letter is (with the Computer Modern fonts) 8.2pt high._
I think when I'm setting the size  to 12 or 14 pt it will be 12 or 14 pt too. For uppercase, it's just a slight  enlargement to, such as 12.1 or 14.2 pt.

Comment: @aggy I did the measurement with a 12pt font size.

Comment: `\topskip` = font size?

Comment: @aggy Usually so.

Comment: OK. How about `\singlespacing`, `\onehalfspacing`. What is their connection with `\linespread`? Thank you very much for the answer. This enlights.

Comment: @aggy If you need enlarged leading, you need to make a similar computation; first count the lines, then adjust the linespread. Please, make a fresh question for the new details; but I insist I wouldn't bother for a couple of millimeters.